# Importing Data from a CSV with Scientific Notation field into Open Edge

Tags: openedge, scientific-notation

I am Importing Data from a CSV File, which contains a Scientific Notation field into Open Edge ( Progress ).

The problem appears to be that Open Edge does not handle scientific notation directly.

So, I am receiving an error:

> ** Invalid character in numeric input E. (76)

How can be done to read the information and get the decimal value to use it.

Any further solutions welcome!

Comment: You are correct.  OpenEdge has no native support for scientific notation.

Comment: I was thinking to upload the table from SQL Server to Progress... ¿is there a way to get around this problem by doing by this mean? just wondering, because in sql server the field is decimal?

Comment: That depends on how you want to upload it.  If you are using some intermediate program that can connect to both databases and which understands the datatypes of both and can assign one to the other then, sure, no problem.  But in your original case you have some text that is formatted in a way that OpenEdge does not natively understand and you are trying to use the OE tools to load it.

Comment: That's correct!!, right now i will use the information by a program on open edge and get the information. But, I was thinking to MSSQL by a SSIS package upload the information on diary basis, then any program could use it in progress database, but had so many problems to build the package so i went to plain text upload and got this not so common situation ( scientific notation ).... I have 5 years on progress and never been aware of this.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was for now, to read it as character and get the exponent apart, then to reunite them in a formula:

> def var a as char.
>
> def var f as decimal.
>
> a = "4.7760555321528834E-2".
>
> f = decimal(entry(1,a,"E")) * exp(10,decimal(entry(2,a,"E"))).
>
> disp a format "X(20)" skip.
>
> disp f format " >>>>>>>>>>9.999999999" .

Comment: When importing from csv I generally import everything as character and then process it. You get a lot more control over error handling that way.